# Необработанные строки

Tags: django, django-filter

В базе данных хранится строка в таком виде: ***Используйте символ #&8838***, которая передается в шаблон; в таком виде она выводится и на странице. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы на странице вместо строки **#&8838** выводился символ **⊆**? Предполагаю, что нужно использовать модуль **django.utils.safestring**, но не понятно как его использовать в данном случае.

Comment: Сейчас выводится так **Используйте символ #&8838**, а нужно **Используйте символ ⊆**

Answer (score 0):

&#8838 у этого символа такой код.

```html
&#8838
```